how to conditionally extend ticksize length in Echarts
I am trying to create a charts multiple bar in echarts, i want when there is jan(01) first month then its ticks extend 2X then normal size means conditionally
how i can increase ticksize conditionally as i am doing for x axis label in echarts
Is there any way to make itb possible in javascript
Is echarts not support custom function on all property as done in d3.js


const colors = ['#5470C6', '#EE6666'];
option = {
  color: colors,
  tooltip: {
    trigger: 'none',
    axisPointer: {
      type: 'cross'
    }
  },

  legend: {},
  grid: {
    width: 1200
  },
  xAxis: [
    {
      type: 'category',
      axisLabel: {
        formatter: function (value, index) {
          // Convert timestamp to a Date object
          const date = new Date(value);
          const month = date.getMonth() + 1; // Months are zero-based
          const year = date.getFullYear();

          // Check if the month is January
          if (month === 1) {
            // Increment the year and format as needed
            const nextYear = year + 1;
            return `${echarts.format.formatTime(
              'MM',
              date
            )}\n${year}&&${nextYear}`;
          } else {
            // Format the label for other months
            return echarts.format.formatTime('MM', date);
          }
        }
      },
      axisTick: {
        show: true,
        length: 20
      },
      // "offset": 10,
      axisLine: {
        onZero: false,
        lineStyle: {
          color: colors[1]
        }
      },

      data: [
        '2016-1',
        '2016-2',
        '2016-3',
        '2016-4',
        '2016-5',
        '2016-6',
        '2016-7',
        '2016-8',
        '2016-9',
        '2016-10',
        '2016-11',
        '2016-12',
        '2017-1'
      ]
    }
  ],
  yAxis: [
    {
      type: 'value'
    }
  ],
  series: [
    {
      name: 'Precipitation(2015)',
      type: 'bar',
      smooth: true,
      emphasis: {
        focus: 'series'
      },
      data: [
        10, 2.6, 5.9, 9.0, 26.4, 28.7, 70.7, 175.6, 182.2, 48.7, 18.8, 6.0, 2.3
      ]
    }
  ]
};



